# Jackson JSON class structure

Tags: java, android, json, jackson, resttemplate

I'm trying to get the values from a JSON feed in Android using the RestTemplate and Jackson.

Structure of my JSON:

```
{
"fruitstatus": "Good",
"fruits": [
    {
        "name": "Apple",
        "color": "Green"
    },
    {
        "name": "Strawberry",
        "via": "Red"
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
]
}
```

My class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

public class Fruit {
    public String fruitstatus;
    public List<Fruits> fruits;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class Fruits {
        public String name;
        public String color;
    }
}
```

My main class in Android:

```
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

            Fruit fruit = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Fruit.class);
            Fruit.Fruits fFruits = new Fruit.Fruits();
            Log.i("Test:", fFruits.name);
```

I'm having quite some issues getting the values form the inner class, they are usually empty.

How can I find the values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this site. [jsonschema2pojo.](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org)

This will conver your json schemas to Java class. It works for both `Jackson` and `Gson`.